# Problem with Lagrange's Interpolation formula

Tags: lagrange-interpolation

> **Problem**: Given $u_1 = 1, u_2 + u_3 = 6$ and $u_4 + u_5 + u_6 + u_7 + u_8 = 30.$ What is the approximate value of $u_4$ when computed by using Lagrange's interpolation formula?

I tried to solve it as described here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lagranges-interpolation/

But unable to put the components together.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? You should show your work so that someone can help you get unstuck instead of having to guess at the difficulty you’re having.

Comment: It seems to me x1 = 1, x2 = 2 .. like this and y1 = u1, y2 = u2.. like this.... Now in order to find y4 ( ie u4 ), I need to find y2, y3 etc. How to find them ?